# What is the antonym (opposite) of “email”?

Tags: antonyms, email

What is the antonym (opposite) of “**email**” to refer clearly to "traditional mail" and not to email?

Comment: These are not "opposites".  Is a bus the opposite of a car?  *How do we refer to mail that is sent via the postal service and delivered by a human being?*

Comment: You should state your context.  Are you looking for an informal term or a formal term?

Comment: That's an alternative, not an antonym.

Answer (score 5):

The [Wikipedia entry for Mail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mail) has a few possible terms you could consider.

As an AmE speaker, I use the term *postal mail* to clarify that I'm speaking about physical letters and not electronic messages.

Answer (score 4):

What about **snail mail**?

According to the Cambridge Dictionary

[**snail mail**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/es/diccionario/ingles/snail-mail) [informal humorous]

> letters or messages that are **not sent by email**, but in the post

As pointed by Tᴚoɯɐuo, notice that this term is *informal and mildly derogatory*.

Comment: It should be pointed out that this is an informal, mildly derogatory term.   A law firm, say, wouldn't ask you to send them a duly signed document "via snail mail".

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo You're right. I've updated my answer to highlight that point. Thanks!

Comment: A more formal term for *snail mail* is *letter mail*. Or just *by mail* or *by letter*.

Answer (score 0):

While I agree with **snail mail**, an alternative when referring to large amounts of data is **sneaker net**. Rather than sending the data electronically, the data is copied to a disk or other medium and physically transported (presumably by someone wearing sneakers).

Comment: This is valid in a specific context, one which only a *very* small percentage of people will ever face.   I don't think OP is talking about this, just *traditional delivery of mail* as compared with *electronic delivery of mail*.